# HTTPAppender not found Log4j2

Tags: mule, log4j2, appender

I am trying to use HTTP appender of Log4j2 in my mule project but unfortunately I am receiving  during compile time .

> 2018-12-11 15:56:53,355 main ERROR Error processing element Http ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
>   2018-12-11 15:56:53,389 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "Http1243" for logger config "root"
>   2018-12-11 15:56:53,471 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
>   INFO  2018-12-11 15:56:53,543 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:

Following is my configaration :

```
<Http name="Http1243" url="https://localhost:80082/test/log4j/">
        <Property name="X-Java-Runtime" value="$${java:runtime}" />
        <JsonLayout properties="true" />
        </Http>

        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="DAILY_LOG" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Http1243" />
        </AsyncRoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your log4j2 version is less than 2.7.
HttpAppender only available in log4j2 version higher than 2.6. Use version 2.7 or higher.
You can get latest version from
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: I have the following in my POM . I have 2.11.1 version , but still getting the same error . Do we need any specific library for this .

Comment: Did you get it resolved? I am also facing the same error